# extracting value based on another column

Tags: r, extract

I have a function that spits out a matrix, such as:

```
      x freq
1 FALSE   40
2  TRUE    6
```

but when there are no FALSE values, I get

```
     x freq
1 TRUE   46
```

I want to extract the freq value when x=TRUE.
If there are are always both FALSE and TRUE values, I can do

```
> matrix [2,2]
[1] 6
```

But I would like to be able to extract the TRUE value whether or not there are FALSE values. Does anyone know how I can do that? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What you've shown there is not a `matrix` but a `data.frame` since `matrix` in R can only be a single type.  Also, please spend some time reading some of R FAQs and introductions that are available online... `yourdata$freq[yourdata$x]`

Comment: I see you have not accepted an answer for any question you have asked. If you want more attention given to this, and future questions, I would recommend going back and acknowledging the answers people have given previously.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As @Justin said, you might be working with a `data.frame` instead of a `matrix`. All the better. Using your example above, if your data.frame looks as follows:

```
df <- data.frame(x=c(FALSE,TRUE), freq=c(40, 6))
> df
      x freq
1 FALSE   40
2  TRUE    6
```

The following will get you what you want irrespective of whether there are `FALSE` values or not.

```
df$freq[df$x==TRUE]
[1] 6
```

**EDIT**: As @DWin points out, you can simplify further by using the fact that `df$x` is logical:

```
> df$freq[df$x]
[1] 6
> df$freq[!df$x]
[1] 40
```

For example:

```
> df2 <- data.frame(x=TRUE, freq=46)
> df2
     x freq
1 TRUE   46
```

Still works:

```
> df2$freq[df2$x==TRUE]
[1] 46
```

Comment: Very helpful. Thanks to all who responded.

Comment: If df$x is logical, then the `==TRUE` is superfluous.