# Replace all rows after the first one for a particular condition the same in R

Tags: r

imagine that this was a data frame in R (I wasn't sure how to import my data frame). I would like to go from this to

| word | cat |
| --- | --- |
| book | distracter |
| cat | target |
| cat | distracter |
| cat | target |
| apple | distracter |
| apple | target |

to

| word | cat |
| --- | --- |
| book | distracter |
| cat | target |
| cat | target |
| cat | target |
| apple | distracter |
| apple | distracter |

I know I can do this by slowly going through every index and changing them manually but is there a better way to replace the values after the first occurrence for a particular condition with the same value?

Currently doing the below for every row I want changed.

`data1$cat[3] <- "target"`

Note. What I am trying to do is when I first see a new word "cat", the corresponding value to that in the cat category is "target". Now I want to replace any rows after it with the same "target" value. So in the 3rd row, I should replace distracter with target. As well as the 6th row, where I need to replace "target" with "distracter"!

Any help would be awesome! Thanks!

**Reproducible sample data**

```
structure(list(word = c("book", "cat", "cat", "cat", "apple", 
"apple"), cat = c("distracter", "target", "distracter", "target", 
"distracter", "target")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [extracting value based on another column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18706665/extracting-value-based-on-another-column)

Comment: So, basically, you need to extract the values of one column based on another column, and then set the new values...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this is what you have in mind. I imagined you are supposed to replace every other rows with the first value of every group of words:

```
library(dplyr)


df %>%
  group_by(word) %>%
  add_count() %>%
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>%
  mutate(cat = ifelse(n > 1 & id >= 2, first(cat), cat)) %>%
  select(-c(n, id))


# A tibble: 6 x 2
# Groups:   word [3]
  word  cat       
  <chr> <chr>     
1 book  distracter
2 cat   target    
3 cat   target    
4 cat   target    
5 apple distracter
6 apple distracter
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the second column is named "cat", I assume you want to label every entry where "word" equals to "cat" as "target"?

```
data$cat[data$word == "cat"] <- "target"
data$cat[data$word != "cat"] <- "distractor"
```